# Storing luggage for a few hours near Jacob K. Javits Convention Center

Tags: new-york-city, luggage-storage

Before I head home on Saturday, I want to tour upper Manhattan  for one last time.

My bus leaves from Jacob K. Javits Convention Center and my carry bag is very heavy to carry with me during the tour of Manhattan.

Where do I keep the bag this Saturday (near Jacob K. Javits Convention Center)?

Some people seem to recommend keeping it at a nearby hotel but when I asked the bell man at New Yorker he said it was for guests only.

Can I check it at another hotel? Which would be a better option?

Are there places where I can rent a locker for a few hours?

Answer (score 4):

Your best and quite possibly the only option would storing it at [Penn Station](http://www.nyc.com/visitor_guide/luggage_storage.75878/editorial_review.aspx) in the Amtrak luggage storage facility or [Schwartz Travel](http://www.schwartztravel.com/), which offers similar service.

If you're staying in the hotel you can take advantage of their storage facility even after a checkout.

Comment: That's right.  There are absolutely no luggage storage facilities anywhere in Manhattan other than the one in Penn Station. I once spoke to a local cop about it - and he said this was due to security concerns that somebody may put something malicious in the luggage and store it there.